# Use nohup and return to terminal and pipe to logger

Tags: linux, command-line, nohup

I can redirect output to `logger` like this:

`nohup bin/mytask | logger`

But the process hangs, and my cursor doesn't return to the terminal after the command is sent. (I would have to return to terminal with `ctrl` `c` and I don't want to quit the process.

So I try this command:

`nohup bin/mytask & | logger`

But I get this error:

`bash: syntax error near unexpected token`|'`

How can redirect the output to the `logger` and then return tom the terminal?

Comment: There's a contradiction in this question in the form of a process that is "done" that the questioner does not want to quit because it is still running.  It cannot be both done and still running.

Comment: Fixed the contextual error ... I changed it to "But the process hangs, and my cursor doesn't return to the terminal after the command is sent."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nohup bin/mytask | logger &
```

`&` is a command separator, just like `;` and `|`, and you have to background a whole pipeline, not just one command in it.